# why are container agents locked into D2 instances on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

Title says it all... Agent Container serveces are locked into D2 instances when I would like to choose a different size for my containers... Why would it be locked?

Comment: This seems to have changed today since you can change the size of the VM on the template while creating the azure container service.

Answer (score 0):

The agents are not locked and never have been. They are configurable in both the CLI (`az acs create --help`) and the portal:

[image]